# Creating a NUnit constraint meaning "{collection} does not contain {item}"

Tags: c#, nunit

I'm struggling to make an assertion about the absence of a particular item in an enumeration. Specifically, this is what my test looks like:

```
// Take an item from a queue of scheduled items...
ItemQueue pendingQueue = schedule.PendingItems; // PendingItems is an IEnumerable<int>
int item = pendingQueue.FirstItem;

// ...process the item...
processor.DoSomethingWith(item);

// ...and the schedule must not contain the item anymore:
Assert.That(schedule.PendingItems, Does.Not.Contain(item));
```

Of course, **Does.Not.Contain** is not a valid nUnit constraint. How can I express it in a valid fluent syntax?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

```
Assert.That(schedule.PendingItems, Has.No.Member(item))
```

Only with NUnit 2.4 / 2.5

Answer (score 20):

Use the [CollectionAssert](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=collectionAssert&r=2.4) method:

```
CollectionAssert.DoesNotContain(schedule.PendingItems, item);
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are using NUnit 2.4 / 2.5 you may checkout the [collection constraints](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=collectionConstraints&r=2.5.5).